# Avoid Open ScriptEditor of Google Spreasheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, editor

In my google spreadsheet, my scripts and custom function already work. However, I  want to prevent other users from accessing the script editor, but they should be able to access/run the custom menus.

Is this possible, if so could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has Edit access to the document they have access to the script. If you need to remove access to the script you will need to publish it as an add-on.  This is a pretty simple process especially if you are publishing it for your own work domain.

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/

Comment: you can also publish an add on to a specific list of users or to a Google group in your domain

Comment: Yes that is correct. But how can i avoid to others user open the scripteditor when they open spreadsheet.... if they can ... also can change the code of client side that call another code liki Library or addonds

Comment: Yes, only way is work with ADDONS. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @SpencerEaston , I think that is possible that ADDON only work for users with editor rights? When editors users work with sheet with protection MENU ADDON is disabled ... right?